# bundle install works, but bundle-show gives error "rails.git is not yet checked out. Please run `bundle install`"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, rubygems, bundler

I've recently updated our Gemfile to use a forked copy rails on our github account. We've created a custom branch off the 2.3-stable branch (which I'll call `the_bugfix_branch`) and added gemspecs for each of the gems to make them findable by bundler.

My Gemfile has the following:

```
git 'git://github.com/ourgithub/rails.git', :branch => "the_bugfix_branch"  do
  # Note: load-order is essential for dependencies
  gem 'activesupport', '2.3.2' # this must go first
  gem 'actionpack',    '2.3.2' # this must go second
  gem 'actionmailer',  '2.3.2' 
  gem 'activerecord',  '2.3.2' 
  gem 'activeresource','2.3.2' 
  gem 'rails',         '2.3.2' # this must go last
end
```

`bundle install` runs happily giving me (amongst all the rest of the gem output):

```
Using actionpack (2.3.2) from git://github.com/ourgithub/rails.git (at the_bugfix_branch) 
Using actionmailer (2.3.2) from git://github.com/ourgithub/rails.git (at the_bugfix_branch) 
Using activesupport (2.3.2) from git://github.com/ourgithub/rails.git (at the_bugfix_branch) 
Using activerecord (2.3.2) from git://github.com/ourgithub/rails.git (at the_bugfix_branch) 
Using activeresource (2.3.2) from git://github.com/ourgithub/rails.git (at the_bugfix_branch) 
...
Using rails (2.3.2) from git://github.com/ourgithub/rails.git (at the_bugfix_branch)
...
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

I then checkin and commit Gemfile.lock which contains:

```
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/ourgithub/rails.git
  revision: 3fc562f9b1def3ad9a7abbfd5ccfa713a6dbc39f
  branch: the_bugfix_branch
  specs:
    actionmailer (2.3.2)
      actionpack (= 2.3.2)
    actionpack (2.3.2)
      actionpack (= 2.3.2)
    activerecord (2.3.2)
      activesupport (= 2.3.2)
    activeresource (2.3.2)
      activesupport (= 2.3.2)
    activesupport (2.3.2)
    rails (2.3.2)
      actionmailer (= 2.3.2)
      actionpack (= 2.3.2)
      activerecord (= 2.3.2)
      activeresource (= 2.3.2)
      activesupport (= 2.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.3)
```

However if I try to spin up the server, it tells me:

```
The git source git://github.com/ourgithub/rails.git is not yet checked out. Please run `bundle install` before trying to start your application
```

I also get the exact same message if I try `bundle show rails` or `bundle check`:

```
> bundle show rails
The git source git://github.com/ourgithub/rails.git is not yet checked out. Please run `bundle install` before trying to start your application
> bundle check
git://github.com/ourgithub/rails.git (at the_bugfix_branch) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install`
```

If I try `bundle install --deployment` (just for kicks) it gives:

```
> bundle install --deployment
You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
updated Gemfile.lock to version control.

You have added to the Gemfile:
* source: git://github.com/ourgithub/rails.git (at the_bugfix_branch)

You have deleted from the Gemfile:
* source: git://github.com/ourgithub/rails.git (at the_bugfix_branch)

You have changed in the Gemfile:
* activeresource from `git://github.com/ourgithub/rails.git (at the_bugfix_branch)` to `no specified source`
* activerecord from `git://github.com/ourgithub/rails.git (at the_bugfix_branch)` to `no specified source`
* actionmailer from `git://github.com/ourgithub/rails.git (at the_bugfix_branch)` to `no specified source`
* actionpack from `git://github.com/ourgithub/rails.git (at the_bugfix_branch)` to `no specified source`
* activesupport from `git://github.com/ourgithub/rails.git (at the_bugfix_branch)` to `no specified source`
* rails from `git://github.com/ourgithub/rails.git (at the_bugfix_branch)` to `no specified source`
```

I've clearly *not* just changed my Gemfile, and I most certainly *have* run bundle install since the time I did add that stuff to the Gemfile.

I've googled for *"is not yet checked out. Please run `bundle install` before trying to start your application"* and all the *"`bundle install` won't work"* questions that I can find seem to say *"just run `bundle install` then checkin your copy of `Gemfile.lock`"*... which I've clearly done. They also tend to be about bundle-install failing on production, but mine fails this way also on development.

I don't think this is a **simple** Gemfile/Gemfile.lock mismatch problem!

Some of the google results tell me to try removing .bundle/config and running it again. I've tried that to the same (lack of) effect.

Specifically, I went through all of the `rm -rf` lines of this troubleshooting guide: https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/blob/master/ISSUES.md before re-running bundle install.

No change in the error message.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Taryn East said:*

> I don't think this is a **simple** Gemfile/Gemfile.lock mismatch problem!

Turns out I was wrong.

The solution was to remove the version-numbers in the Gemfile, and explicitly use the branch instead:

```
git 'git://github.com/ourgithub/rails.git', :branch => "the_bugfix_branch"  do
  # Note: load-order is essential for dependencies
  gem 'activesupport', :branch => "the_bugfix_branch" # this must go first
  gem 'actionpack',    :branch => "the_bugfix_branch" # this must go second
  gem 'actionmailer',  :branch => "the_bugfix_branch" 
  gem 'activerecord',  :branch => "the_bugfix_branch" 
  gem 'activeresource',:branch => "the_bugfix_branch" 
  gem 'rails',         :branch => "the_bugfix_branch" # this must go last
end
```

bundler was getting confused with the version-number on one hand, and the branch on the other.

Explicitly setting the branch for every gem listed, seemed to finally do the trick!